# Convert ViewBag to Model

Tags: model, controller, viewbag

```
public ViewResult Details(int ID)
    {           
        tblMp3 item =  db.tblMp3.Single(t => t.ID == ID);
        ViewBag.Mp3Tags= db.tblTags.Where(c => c.tblMp3.Any(a => a.ID == ID)).ToList();
        return View(item);
    }
```

This is my Controller, I read that it is not recommended to use ViewBag and that I must use Model alternatively but unfortunately I do not know how to do that can any one help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create new class like this:

```
public class Mp3ViewModel
{
   public tblMp3 Item { get;set; }
   public SomeClass Mp3Tags { get;set; }
}
```

And send it to view.

In view you use:

```
@model namespace.Mp3ViewModel
```

now you can use `Model.Item` and `Model.Mp3Tags`

Answer (score 2):

On your View, add this on the first line :

```
@model YouNamespace.tblMp3
```

After, you can use your model's properties :

```
<p>@Model.Title</p>
```